# Determinar si un numero cumple con ciertos estándares

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de que esta función me retorne un valor booleano, al llamarla. 
La misma esta pensada para determinar si un numero clasifica

El problema que tengo es que no me retorna verdadero o falso si no indefinido.

```js
function happyChecker(n, cont = 0) {

    if (n == 1) {    
        return true
    } else if (cont == 8) {
        return false
    } else {
        var arr = [];
        var newNum = 0;
        num = n.toString().split("");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = parseInt(num[i], 10);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            newNum += Math.pow(arr[i], 2);
        }
        cont++
        happyChecker(newNum, cont);

    }
}

console.log(happyChecker(19));
```

Answer (score 3):

El el último `else` no estás devolviendo ningún valor (`return`).

Cambia la última línea de

```
happyChecker(newNum, cont);
```

a

```
return happyChecker(newNum, cont);
```

Con eso, retornarás el valor devuelto por la llamada recursiva, que es lo que buscas.

La solución completa sería algo como:

```js
function happyChecker(n, cont = 0) {

    if (n == 1) {    
        return true
    } else if (cont == 8) {
        return false
    } else {
        var arr = [];
        var newNum = 0;
        var num = n.toString().split("");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = parseInt(num[i], 10);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            newNum += Math.pow(arr[i], 2);
        }
        cont++
        return happyChecker(newNum, cont);

    }
}

console.log(happyChecker(19));
```

Un saludo.

Comment: como detalle, es posible que de un error de variable num no definida. Con poner el var delante estaria solucionado (lo digo por si quieres corregirlo en tu solucion)

Comment: Gracias, hice la edición, un saludo. ;)